# Can we make JMS Producer to use "AmazonSQSAsyncClient" 's method "sendMessageAsync" to send the message?

Tags: jms, amazon-sqs

I have a JMS producer which is using the **AmazonSQSClient**'s **sendMessage** method to produce the message. I want to use the **AmazonSQSAsyncClient**'s **sendMessageAsync** method in my JMS producer. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the `AmazonSQSAsync` client. In spring boot you can just Autowire it.

Now as you can see the `sendMessageAsync` returns a `Future`, so you need to wait for it.

```
amazonSQSAsync.sendMessageAsync("logical queue name", "message").get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

If you prefer you can also use the other method:

```
amazonSQSAsync.sendMessage("logical queue name", "message")
```

It won't return Future but it will timeout if the receive timeout is reached.

Comment: Yes this is using amazon sqs library. What I want to do is I have a JMS implemend in code already; so I want to achieve this using `amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib` which provides JMS implementation.